# Make border width wider than element (not using padding)

Tags: html, css

SCREENSHOT of what I want to achieve: 
(I covered logos and links)

### [image]

I have a header that contains two element : a logos section and a navigation bar.

Now I am trying to create a border-top for the nav element, that is 100% width of the screen in any given size.

I can not use padding-left-right and I would like to avoid using extra markup.

Is this achievable? probably using a :before?

```
<header>
    <div class="site-header">
        some stuff + a full width border in the middle!
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>linka</li>
            <li>link b</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>


.site-header, nav {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
    border-top: 1px solid red; 
}
```

fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/oodrabm2/1/

Comment: *border between the two that is wider than those elements* part is confusing

Comment: sorry I just changed that! Will try to post a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nav should be outside the header or you need to set the width only on site-header and ul not nav like:

```css
.site-header, nav ul {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
    border-top: 1px solid red; 
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="site-header">
        some stuff + a full width border in the middle!
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>linka</li>
            <li>link b</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: can not take nav outside the header (it's a sticky header)

Answer (score 1):

Using `:before` it should be achievable:

```
header {overflow: hidden;}
nav {position: relative;}
nav:before {
    content: ''; 
    height: 1px; 
    background: red;
    width: 500%;
    position: absolute; 
    top: -10px;
    left: -50%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oodrabm2/4/

The idea is to make `:before` element wider than the whole page (or `header` in this case) and combine that with `overflow: hidden` to avoid scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a pseudo-element would be appropriate, and you can place it using `position:absolute`.

```css
.site-header,
nav {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
nav {
  position: relative;
  background: lightblue;
}
nav::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="site-header">some stuff + a full width border in the middle!</div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>linka</li>
      <li>link b</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Updated to 100Vw and doesn't require `overflow:hidden`

Comment: I doubt he will go with vw but unique example though